# A smart bulb I can turn on and off at the wall switch

Tags: lighting, smart-lights

What I would like is a lightbulb that when I turn it on during office hours, it’s a bright white light. And when I turn it on at any other time it’s a dim warm light. I’d like to continue using the wall switch to control if the light is on or off.

I don’t want to use Siri or Alexa or have the bulb turn itself on/off when either it thinks I’m in the room or based on a schedule of when I might be in the room.  I’d just like to use the light switch.

I have a hive central heating system. A couple of days ago, I got one of their cool to warm smart lights: https://www.hivehome.com/products/hive-active-light-cool-to-warm-white

I set a schedule for the brightness and colour I wanted through the day.

However unfortunately it doesn’t do what I want. If you’re turning it on and off using the light switch, it completely ignores the schedule (until the next change in schedule) - it defaults to 100% brightness and whatever the last colour temperature was.

Does anyone make a lightbulb that supports my use case?  Going on various product manufacturers websites, it’s not immediately obvious if any do.

Comment: bulbs that change the light temperature are available off the shelf ... turns on warm, click off/on at the light switch changes to daylight ... etc.

Comment: @jsotola - brilliant idea. I’ve had a look and my local hardware shop sell them: https://www.diy.com/ideas-advice/light-bulb-buying-guide/CC_npcart_400180.art I’ll check them out!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a API, and make that api which can communicate with smart bulb so if you tether with that bulb you can have the option to increase brightness and you can reduce as you want & also you can set the color as you like.. Note: for that purpose you should know to decode and deploy that smart bulb with your code, if you do this you can select as you want

Comment: An interesting idea thank you - I’d not considered going down an API approach. Looking at hive, I don’t think they’ve got an official API. Though looking around, I think Philips do, so I’ll have a look at that. I must admit I’d prefer not to go to the hassle of having to call an API to get this going, but if it’s the only way then I will do :-)